# Installing CDN Tax Receipts For Us

Tags: receipts, donations, cdn-tax-receipts

we are new to CIVICRM! I am wondering if someone could possibly help us with fully installing and setting us up with the the extension CDN Tax Receipts?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CiviCRM! CDN TaxReceipts can be installed through your manage Extensions screen:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/introduction/extensions/#installing-extensions

If you run into config/support issues you can reach out here on SE. Best to ask detailed questions with screenshots.

If you run into a technical issue you can create an issue here:
https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts

A number of Canadian IT companies monitor this GitHub repo (Coop Symbiotic, Mustardseed NonProfit, PeaceWorks and ourselves).

Comment: Not sure, but I think he was asking for info on using it in the USA. We've used it in the states for a bit. Just needs to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Ah right perhaps Us and us refer to US :-) The code is very useful for receipting/tracking/auditing and only has a few Canadian bits - it does not take much to generalize it.